How to make an IP of a website created using Django to be a link and publicaly available to all?
I am a django learner and upon creating a website i realized that the ip of my website is not accessible on all devices but i want it to be accessed on any device using a link.
I haven't tried anything about it because i don't know much about it. I am still in the learning face and am trying to get more knowledge about it.

You should look up a beginner tutorial on youtube for django, and finish it completely.

is this even a django question? if your IP is not accessible to all devices, this is more of a network/firewall/hosting issue than anything to do with Django. As Nesi noted, youtube has a significant number of videos that can help you get a django app up, but it won't solve your hosting issue(s).

You are thinking of deployment and you will have to host the website on a server. I'd highly recommend since you are starting out that you follow all the steps in a tutorial such as this, However if you are exclusively interested in the deployment part this page might be of use to you, as it outlines a few options you could use for deployment far more in detail than I could here.

Thanks a lot. I was looking for solutions and you made me found that. Thanks
